# Sitecore Commerce installer SXA framework install module

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

My Sitecore commerce installer is throwing an error 404 when it tries to access the page http://sxa.sotefront.com/SiteUtilityPages/Installmodules?=...

I made sure my Sitecore XP installer doesn't get interrupted and that the XP is working.

Any idea what could be causing this problem?

[image: Sitecore Commerce Installer]

Answer (score 1):

When you install Sitecore Commerce then it adds a new binding for storefront. You can see the name in your Sitecore Commerce  installation file "Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1". There you can find the hostname provided in "$SiteHostHeaderName" variable.

Can you please double check if you can access your storefront with "http://sxa.sotefront.com" url. Please notice it has http protocol. Please check if "sxa.sotefront.com" binding added with http protocol on your Sitecore site in IIS.

If it still not work then check you have this "InstallPackages.aspx" page in "SiteUtilityPages" folder in your Sitecore site.

Comment: my $SiteHostHeaderName is sxa.storefront.com.  

I can't access the http:\\sxa.storefront.com URL. These are my Sitecore site iss bindings,   "https:*:443:sc10sc.dev.local,https:*:443:sxa.storefront.com,http:*:80:sxa.storefront.com"  

I don't have InstallPackages.aspx in my Sitecore site. The closest thing I have is InstallModules.aspx

Comment: Seems "http:\\sxa.storefront.com" binding exists in your iis "http:*:80:sxa.storefront.com". Can you please check in your host file if you have entry for sxa.storefront.com and it's pointing to 127.0.0.1. for ex. "127.0.0.1 sxa.storefront.com" in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file.

Comment: Also share the error or message getting while accessing http:\\sxa.storefront.com site.

Comment: when I access it in chrome all I get is "404 page not found" in plain black text over white page

Comment: Do you have entry for "sxa.storefront.com" in your host file?

Comment: Are you able to access it on https protocol i.e. https://sxa.storefront.com and can you access https://sc10sc.dev.local site?

Comment: The problem was that I had Sitecore commerce 9 installed. So there were two sxa.store.front domains in my host file, XC 9 and XC 10, which mapped to different ips. I commented out sitecore commerce 9 sxa.store.front from the host file and the commerce installer worked. Thank you

Comment: Great, its worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had Sitecore commerce 9 installed. So there were two sxa.store.front domains in my host file, XC9 and XC10, which mapped to different ips. I commented out Sitecore commerce 9 sxa.store.front from the host file and the commerce installer worked.